# firebase's firestore.setDoc() - promise doesn't resolve

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I was [following the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en&authuser=0#web-modular-api_2), trying to set up and work with Firestore when I came upon this problem. I am using Next.js, though I don't see why that would be an issue.

Here's my code:

"product.firebase.ts":

```
import { doc, getFirestore, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { initialize } from '@/lib/firebase.lib';
import { randomString } from '../utils';

export interface IFirebaseProduct {
  name: string;
}

export function isFirebaseProduct(obj: any): obj is IFirebaseProduct {
  return "name" in obj;
}

export async function createProductEntry(entry: IFirebaseProduct){
    const app = initialize();
    const db = getFirestore(app);

    const id: string = randomString(20, 'a');
    await setDoc(doc(db, 'products', id), entry).then(() => console.log("Added item: ", entry));
}
```

"page.tsx":

```
"use client";

import {
  IFirebaseProduct,
  createProductEntry,
} from "@/lib/firebase/product.firebase";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function AddProduct() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState<string>("");
  const sendData = (entry: IFirebaseProduct) => {
    try {
      createProductEntry(entry).then(() => console.log("Added item: ", entry));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setInput(e.target.value);
          console.log(input);
        }}
      ></input>
      <button onClick={() => sendData({ name: input })}>Submit</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Neither of the `console.log()`s show anything, my database stays intact. i.e. the promise never resolves or rejects. Why would that be?

Here's the `initialize()` function, in case it helps:

```
export function initialize() {
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    // Enable analytics. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/
    if ("measurementId" in firebaseConfig && app.options.projectId) {
      getAnalytics(app);
      getPerformance(app);
    }
  }
  console.log("Firebase succesfully initialized.");
  return app;
}
```

where firebaseConfig is an object with all of the app's services, copied and pasted from the Firebase console.

Comment: If the promise rejects, none of the code you've shown would notice. For example, the try/catch in sendData can only catch synchronous errors, not a rejected promise. Could you try making `sendData` an `async` function and `await` the call to `createProductEntry(entry)`, so that the catch can work?

Comment: @NicholasTower Done. Still nothing shows up in my console, besides my input and the initialize success log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: I implemented an API Route Handler in Next, as such:

```
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { initialize } from "@/lib/firebase.lib";
import { createProductEntry, isFirebaseProduct } from "@/lib/firebase/product.firebase";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request, res: NextApiResponse){
    initialize();
    res = await req.json();
    const parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
    if(isFirebaseProduct(parsed)){
        await createProductEntry(parsed)
            .then(() => console.log("Item added: ", parsed))
            .catch(() => console.log("Failed to add item: ", parsed));
        return NextResponse.json("Firestore: POST success.");
    }
    return NextResponse.json("Firestore: POST failed.")
}
```

Then, sending a POST request in Postman, console returned:

`[2023-06-26T20:10:11.700Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.23.0): GrpcConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x668d4616 error. Code: 3 Message: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid resource field value in the request.`

I was running `firebase.initializeApp()` while getting the config data from .env.local. Writing out those strings in the code solved it for me. Now, reading data from .env.local is a whole other issue.